# the app stopped on white screen when using microsoft intune in Xamarin.Android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

after installing (Microsoft.Intune.MAM.Remapper.Tasks) plugin I get the following errors ,

the app stops on the white screen,

The reference I was following ([click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-xamarin#enabling-intune-app-protection-policies-in-your-android-mobile-app)),

I found a note in the reference link (If you encounter a blank, white screen in your application on launch, then you may need to force the navigation calls to execute on the main thread)
you can find this note  in the Troubleshooting section, I don't understand what he meant

Note: Before installing this plugin the app works fine.

The pictures below give more information about my code

**MainApplication.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Firebase;
using Microsoft.Intune.Mam.Client.App;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;

   namespace test.Droid
    {
    #if DEBUG
        [Application(Debuggable = false)]
    #else
        [Application]
    #endif
        public class MainApplication : MAMApplication, MAMApplication.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
        {
            public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
            {
            }
    
            public override void OnMAMCreate()
            {
                base.OnMAMCreate();
    
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {     
                    FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";
                    FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
                }
    
                RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
              
            }
    
            public override void OnTerminate()
            {
                base.OnTerminate();
                UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
            }
    
            public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
            }
    
            public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
            {
            }
    
            public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
            {
            }
    
            public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
            {
                CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
            }
    
            public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
            {
            }
    
            public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
            {
                CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
            }
    
            public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

[image]

*i have 3 class for MainActivity*

**MainActivity 1**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Almond.Core;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;

namespace Almond.Droid
{
    [Activity(ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : ES.Droid.MainActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

        public MainActivity() : base(new Almond.Core.AppSetup())
        {
        }

        protected override void OnMAMCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            Instance = this;

            base.OnMAMCreate(bundle);

            FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            DisplayCrashReport();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);

        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

       
    }
}
```

**MainActivity 2 (inherit by MainActivity 1)**

```
using System;
using Android.OS;
using ES.Xam.Forms;
using Plugin.Fingerprint;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace ES.Droid
{
    public class MainActivity : ES.Mobile.Android.AppActivity
    {
        public MainActivity(Xam.Forms.AppSetup appsetup)
        {

            AppContainer.Initialize(appsetup);
        }

        protected override void OnMAMCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => this);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var ex = ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).GetBaseException();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("**MAIN ACTIVITY EXCEPTION**\n\n" + ex);
                    InsightsManager.Report(ex, InsightsManager.Severity.Error);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            };

            FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Almond.Droid.Resource.Layout.toolbar;
            FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Almond.Droid.Resource.Layout.tabs;

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            base.OnMAMCreate(bundle);
        }
    }
}
```

**Base Activity (inherit by MainActivity 2)**

```
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace ES.Mobile.Android
{
    public class AppActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnMAMCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
        }

        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed);
        }
    }
}
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The MainThread class allows applications to run code on the main thread of execution, and to determine if a particular block of code is currently running on the main thread.
for more information check the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread

Answer (score 0):

Setting my Android targetSdkVersion to 28 fixed my issue.

Set
android:targetSdkVersion="28" In AndroidManifest.xml

It's working fine on all android devices (Android OS version upto 12)